# ObjectOutputStream read in other language

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I used to save items in Android using Android Studio with Java. But now I want to read in exactly that data in my rewritten app in Flutter SDK (Dart language). But it seems that the files that are written are very Java specific. This is the save and load method in Java.

```
public void save(Item item)
{
    String json = gson.toJson(item);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput("item_"+ item.getUid(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(json);
        os.close();
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private Item loadItem(String fileName)
{
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object object = is.readObject();
        Item item = null;
        String json = (String)object;
        item = gson.fromJson(json, Item.class);
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        return item;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And now for reading it in Dart

```
Uint8List bytes = f.readAsBytesSync();
var data = bytes.buffer.asByteData();
// HOW TO DETECT JAVA
if (?SOMETHING?) { }
```

The length of `bytes` is quite large. It is an array of length = 3 245 500.
The length of the json string should be between 740 and 840 bytes long (i.e. a relatively short json).

How could I read in only the json part and not the entire Java 'overhead'/'java serialization format'
[image]

Comment: I would recommend you read your data in Java and switch to serializing as json, xml, or some other format that is not intimately tied to Java. Using Java serialization for this is the wrong tool, and trying to read it in another language is very painful. Also, it is pretty weird to convert something to json, and then write out that string to an `ObjectOutputStream`, why not just write out the json directly to a `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: *"files that are written are very Java specific"* You are correct. The [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) is for writing binary files to be read by `ObjectInStream` *(even says so right there in the javadoc)*, and is not for general communication with other languages. If you want to exchange data with other languages, then you should choose a language-agnostic format like XML or JSON.

Comment: In short, remove the `ObjectOutputStream` (maybe replace it with an `OutputStreamWriter`), and write the json directly to file without wrapping it in Java's object serialization format.

Comment: Mark Rotteveel is right, though with a hex editor you might find out how to extract the json part (UTF-8 string).

Comment: The problem is that the Java version has been dispatched more than a year ago and that now the app is to be replaced in Flutter, so replacing the old code it is not an option as there are still existing items in the old format that need to be read

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently doing is:

1. Serialize to JSON
2. Serialize the Java String with JSON data using Java serialization

Instead, change your code to:

1. Serialize to JSON (directly to file, or first to string, then to file using `OutputStreamWriter` wrapping a `FileOutputStream`).

Trying to reimplement Java serialization in another language is extremely painful, and your current usage of Java serialization makes little sense, and it is unnecessary overhead and only makes your life harder. Remove it from the mix and write the JSON directly to file.

It will simplify your code, and removes the need to implement Java serialization in Dart.

To be able to handle current files written in this combination of Java serialization wrapping JSON data, I would recommend using some extra code in your Java application to detect if a file is Java serialization and if so do a one-off conversion to store the JSON directly.

Alternatively, you can read up on the Java serialization protocol in [Java Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).

Comment: I indeed noticed that what I did earlier was plain wrong. I thought I was simply writing files to memory but it turns out that I was doing Java specific stuff. But the app now has been dispatched to thousands of users. So ideally, I could decrypt the Java format and extract the bytes

Comment: @WouterVandenputte I suggest releasing a new version that will read the serialized file and then write it out as normal JSON, from then on you can use the JSON. I guess that will be simpler than implementing (partial) Java deserialization in Dart.